# how to get single id from array

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

need help , I am new in laravel framework,here how we can passed the checkpoint id this is my code.

```
 $data['checkpoints'] = CheckpointTemplate::where('checklist_template_id', $data['checklist']->checklist_template_id)->where('is_flexible',0)->orderby('sort_order', 'asc')->orderby('sort_order', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
```

this working fine, but here how to passed
    `$data['checkpoint_error_msgs'] =` `CheckpointErrormsg::where('checkpoint_id',**$data['checkpoints']->id**)-> orderby('error_message', 'asc')->lists('error_message', 'error_message');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$errorMessages = CheckpointErrormsg::where(
'checkpoint_id','=',$data['checkpoints']['id']
)->orderby('error_message', 'asc')->lists('error_message', 'error_message');
```

Since you called `toArray()`. The variable is an array and no longer an object.

`->id` would be accessing an objects member variable.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['checkpoints']); $i++) { 
    $id = $data['checkpoints'][$i]['id'];
    $errorMessages = CheckpointErrormsg::where('checkpoint_id','=',$id)->orderby('error_message', 'asc')->lists('error_message', 'error_message');
 }
```

Comment: yes, I have try this way  but I got error Undefined index: id

Comment: The query must not be returning a valid array, or one that does not have an index of id. Add a var_dump($data); to see what the data looks like.

Comment: this is my actual output:

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6e8a7bfc9b664ef3ad9812b7605e2304
            [checklist_template_id] => 5f0c18cec0f64fe7acd984ccd0d3a03c
            [name] => abc
            [label] => abc
            [type] => radiolist
            [value] => 0,1,2
            [sort_order] => 0
            [information] => 
            [is_flexible] => 0
            [needed_certificate] => 0
            [error_messages] => 
            [created_at] => 2016-12-22 04:50:35
            [updated_at] => 2016-12-22 04:50:35
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

Comment: [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => b551b723eb864a318c0a4a8fc3da6ba6
            [checklist_template_id] => 5f0c18cec0f64fe7acd984ccd0d3a03c
            [name] => 123
            [label] => 123
            [type] => radiolist
            [value] => 0,1,2
            [sort_order] => 1
            [information] => test
            [is_flexible] => 0
            [needed_certificate] => 0
            [error_messages] => 
            [created_at] => 2016-12-19 06:17:13
            [updated_at] => 2016-12-20 04:05:45
            [deleted_at] => 
        ) )

Comment: Use $data[0]['id'] then. Or if you need to run that query for all CheckpointTemplate objects then you need to loop through the size of $data.

Comment: I trying this var_dump($data[0]['id']); but I got error for Undefined offset: 0

Comment: foreach($data as $key=>$value){ var_dump($key); var_dump($value); }      Also it is very important to have x-debug set up so you can set breakpoints in your PHP code.

Comment: foreach($data['checkpoints'] as $key=>$value){
          var_dump($key); 
          var_dump($value);
           }

Comment: What is the value dump?

Comment: values: array (size=14)
  'id' => string '6e8a7bfc9b664ef3ad9812b7605e2304' (length=32)
  'checklist_template_id' => string '5f0c18cec0f64fe7acd984ccd0d3a03c' (length=32)
  'name' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  'label' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  'type' => string 'radiolist' (length=9)
  'value' => string '0,1,2' (length=5)
  'sort_order' => int 0
  'information' => string '' (length=0)
  'is_flexible' => int 0
  'needed_certificate' => int 0
  'error_messages' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['checkpoints']); $i++) { var_dump($data['checkpoints'][$i]['id']); }

Comment: all id's displayed

Comment: string '6e8a7bfc9b664ef3ad9812b7605e2304' (length=32)
string 'b551b723eb864a318c0a4a8fc3da6ba6' (length=32)
string '390d703eee20483b90a8dd41c7715f81' (length=32)
string '491237d94424455a92427b8471abffd7' (length=32)
string '75475cf6734049ef9bdd6281ba1277b6' (length=32)
string 'f04ce64eb7734427abd656cf10d9c60c' (length=32)
string '0efb675cbd3645399074bd6745156ae6' (length=32)..........

Comment: Your problem is solved now. Use that loop to access the strings in the query. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: sorry , I am new in how we can use , I have try this ways but i got error

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['checkpoints']); $i++) { 
        $data['checkpoint_error_msgs'] = CheckpointErrormsg::where('checkpoint_id',$data['checkpoints'][$i]['id'])-> orderby('error_message', 'asc')->lists('error_message', 'error_message');
        }

Comment: $data['checkpoint_error_msgs'][] will allow you to keep adding to the array. If not you keep overwriting it.

Comment: I am not understand please

Comment: What is the problem you are having now? You might want to ask another question if the accessing ID from array is solved.

Comment: here how to passed

Comment: where condition inside how to passed

Comment: $data['checkpoint_error_msgs'] = CheckpointErrormsg::where('checkpoint_id',$data['checkpoints'][$i]['id'])-> orderby('error_message', 'asc')->lists('error_message', 'error_message');

Comment: Please create another question as this question has been solved. You can use ->andWhere or ->where to add additional query params.

Comment: Really very Sorry !

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['checkpoints']); $i++) { 
    $id = $data['checkpoints'][$i]['id'];
    $errorMessages = CheckpointErrormsg::where('checkpoint_id','=',$id)->orderby('error_message', 'asc')->lists('error_message', 'error_message');
 }

Comment: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[1116]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty